# Can i use で instead of に in this context

Tags: grammar, particles

In the phrase "ATMはビルの１階にあります"
Can i say ATMはビルの１階であります?
Someone told me it doesn't sound natural. But i didn't understand why

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use で in this case. 
The following page lists several examples of what makes で and に different: 
https://www.kanshudo.com/grammar/%E3%81%A7_%E3%81%AB

In particular, first section mentions:

> For location, で is used to mark the location where an event occurred (ie, a focus on action). に is used to indicate object locations, destinations or directions (in the absence of a specific 'event').

I think this applies well to your sentence.

Comment: In a comment on my (now deleted) answer, @naruto pointed out that ATMはビルの1階です is perfectly reasonable Japanese. This question is a little tricky because the answer to "can で be used with ある in this way?" is really "no" from a pure grammar standpoint, but the sentence works anyway because the copula in Japanese is so flexible. Consequently, "you can't use で here" is not true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I did not think about this interpretation. Indeed it does not sound natural to me to use であります for the location of an object (while です does indeed). I can only think of examples using であります to refer to the state of something/someone (like 吾輩は猫である).

Comment: Yeah, I made the exact same mistake. The である really throws you off here. I feel the same way about である sounding very weird, but I'm not entirely sure it actually changes the meaning/is ungrammatical or wrong. It's just very weird.